# Is it possible to use XHTML design for android application instead of XML design?

Tags: android, xhtml

Is their any possibility to use XHTML design for android application instead of XML design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use a WebView and render HTML inside of that, but you'd be much better off just learning Android's XML, or using the drag-and-drop Interface Builder in the Eclipse Plugin, which is actually pretty good since it was revamped earlier this year.

Answer (score 3):

XHTML is a specific vocabulary for web pages; XML is a grammar for representing data. Both are standards from http://w3.org/

XHTML is a *document markup* language, like HTML. (Except, HTML is defined in the SGML grammar, and XHTML limits itself to the XML subset of that grammar.)

XML is a grammar (of sorts; this is a simplification) to define various data and document markup types.

Neither are, *per se*, used to develop applications; however, the Android SDK has several "small languages" that it uses that are defined in terms of XML for things like the manifest file and user interface layouts. These *can not* be substituted for another language, even one that looks similar on the surface, like XHTML.

It's roughly analogous to: Both English and French use fairly similar punctuation and the same alphabet, just as all XML dialects have similar notation, but even though they may look the same, it does not mean that one can substitute French for English at will.

You may see reference to "applications built using XHTML" or "...HTML;" typically, in fact, these are applications which *produce* HTML (or XHTML) output, or interact with/modify existing HTML/XHTML documents. The applications themselves are written in JavaScript if they run in the web browser; or some other language (Perl, PHP, Ruby, Python, Lisp, C++, even JavaScript again) if they run on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you'd have to use the XML format to create an acutal layout within Android (and then use code within Android to control the interface). However, a good alternative would be to use the WebView class, which allows you to display a webpage within your application. This would likely writing a small amount of XML layout to display that view, but from there you can just make your "app" a webpage and control it however you best see fit (server-side processing if you have it on the actual "web" or perhaps JavaScript).

This may not be the only option, but it should work well.

Read more about WebViews here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

Comment: Or, what Robamaton said. Same thought with a few more options! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could, although you'd have to define an xslt transform that will translate the xhtml into android's xml language.  You'd probably be confined to a small subset of xhtml, though.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML is just one application of XML. XHTML is in fact XML. To answer your second question, yes you must use XML everywhere the documentation tells you you must. Sometimes you can do things programatically - but its probably easier to do it in XML, especially if you use the right tools.